# mapping.txt file is not getting generated when using Proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am facing issue while obfuscating my app using proguard.

I am able to use proguard and it is generating mapping.txt when i am creating a new application in android studio, however mapping.txt is not being generated when i am trying to use proguard on a project migrated from eclipse to android studio.

Following is my proguard-rules.pro file

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-keepdirectories
-keeppackagenames javax.mail.**
-keeppackagenames javax.activation.**
-keeppackagenames com.sun.mail.**
-keeppackagenames myjava.**
-keeppackagenames org.apache.harmony.**
-keeppackagenames mailcap.**
-keeppackagenames mimetypes.**
-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.internet.** {*;}

-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}

-keep class javax.ws.rs.** { *; }

-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
-dontwarn javax.security.**

-ignorewarnings
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

Comment: please post your proguard-rules file as well

Comment: I had a similar problem. I forgot to change minifyEnabled to true in build.gradle :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try removing following lines from your file:

```
-dontobfuscate
.
.
.
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

first line seems to disable obfuscation and last one seems to copy mapping file on a location other then default.

Comment: If you remove -dontobfuscate from proguard-rules file then your shared-preferences  data will not work if you change the versionCode.

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat obfuscation of code has nothing to do with data saved with the app including shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Remove -dontobfuscate from the whole project and you will get your mapping file generated under build/outputs/mapping/..